# Dealing with date formats from JSON to save in Django DateField

Tags: python, django

I'm getting validation errors in django when trying to save a date from a json string.

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'31 Oct 2016' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

what the best/simplest way to convert the date string to the correct format?

The relevant model:

```
  class Product(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    region = models.ForeignKey(PowerRegion)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The relevant part of the scraper feeding the model:

```
source = base_url + product_url
    rsp = s.post(source, data=submit_data2, headers=headers)
    product_detail = json.loads(rsp.text, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict) 


product, created = Tariff.objects.get_or_create(unique_id=product_detail['productId'],
                                                   defaults={
                                                       'unique_id': product_detail['productId'],
                                                       'name': product_detail['productName'],
                                                       'supplier': supplier,
                                                       'region': region,
                                                       'payment': payment,
                                                       'end_date': product_detail['productEndDate'],
                                                   })
```

the relevant field from the json comes in this format:

```
productEndDate: "31 Oct 2016"
```

Comment: can you please past your code.

Comment: updated with code thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use django DATE_INPUT_FORMATS (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) settings to specify allowed date format

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ("%d %b %Y",)
```

But take in consideration that this settings will work if you have disabled localization

```
USE_L10N = False
```

Otherwise django will use locale-dictated format.

In case if you need localization enabled, you should create your own locale date format.

EDITED:

The solution that I've provided works for data that is validated via Django Forms before interacting with models, not Django models directly.

You can otherwise use simple datetime.strptime() to change your date string to date object and then pass it to your model:

```
product_date = datetime.strptime(product_detail['productEndDate'], '%d %b %Y')
```

Or you can should first pass data that you receive after making a post request to appropriate form for validation and type conversion (because I didn't see any validation in your code, maybe you just didn't include it here) and only then pass data from the form to model.

Comment: Thanks that still doesn't work for some reason? I've double checked USE_L10N is set to false and there are no other occurrences of it and added DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ("%d %b %Y",) to settings.  Is the issue the data is a string '31 Oct 2016' does it need to be parsed into a date(time) object first?

Comment: Thanks is there a simpler way to validate data going to a django model without using forms.  It seems a bit heavyweight just to use forms to validate data? Is there no in built way to validate data just via models?

Comment: the schema library seems like a perfect way to validate the data without using forms.